# Got Hat Trick, but haven't hit the rep cap yet

Tags: support, winterbash

I threw this up on the main meta but figure it's relevant here too. The [description](http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/) for Hat Trick is:

> hit the reputation cap on three different days

I just [earned](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/31292/barry#winter-bash) this hat, but this is my [reputation](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/31292/barry?tab=reputation) today so far. Note that I have two accepted answers, so I didn't actually hit the rep cap. I hope to actually earn the cap, but I haven't quite gotten there yet:

[image]

So **either** there's a bug in the hat calculations that don't actually take into account rep cap correctly **or** there's a bug in in the description for Hat Trick and it should just say "hit at least 200 reputation on three different days." Most likely, just fix the latter?

Oh, and I'm keeping the hat. Regardless. Note that the [badge](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/badges) description for Legendary just says 200 rep, not [rep cap](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: @balpha How is it not a bug? Text says one thing, behavior is another. One of those two is wrong.

Answer (score 5):

To be honest, in my head I automatically replaced "rep cap" with "reach 200", like the Epic/Legendary/Mortarboard work. But you're right, they didn't write 200. I guess it's a wording issue, the behavior is as expected.

What I didn't expect, was to get the hat even without actually hitting 200:

[image]

I still haven't reached 200 today btw. As far as I know this way it wouldn't count yet for Epic/Legendary, but apparently good enough for hats. Sweet!

Posted on MSE: [Got Hat Trick, at 199](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271088/got-hat-trick-at-199)

Comment: But Epic and Legendary say "Earn 200 daily reputation", they don't say anything about rep cap. So those descriptions are fine at least.

Comment: You're right, I rephrased that part. I was probably biased when writing the first version, being aware of a more obvious anomaly I noticed earlier during the day.

Answer (score 0):

In the SE systems, you cap when you reach 200 points, regardless of whether you actually have a buffer due to bounties and answers or not.  Most of the times when I actually 'cap', I actually do not lose any rep due to a buffer created by an accepted answer.